# Import custom data from another DB to nodes

Tags: feeds, 10

For create/update new nodes I used  the Feeds module.

It works well with CSV/OPML.

But now I need to import a new data from another database, forming result by SQL query.
There are old modules for this:

[Feeds Database](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_db)

[Feeds SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_sql)

For Drupal 10 I cannot find nothing.

Dump from external DB and following import by Feeds module works, but I'd like to get result without intermediate entities like CSV files.

Comment: There is plenty of verbiage on running migrations in Drupal that have existed since Drupal 8 and is in core, plus the Migrate Plus module. What have you tried?

Comment: Migrate Plus, as I understood doesn't have abilities for direct connection to another database.
I need to fetch data from PostgreSQL, where is ERP data located.
Now I fetch csv file from PG by shell script and upload it by module feeds, which does what I want.
My idea is to implement it more straightforward.

Comment: You can absolutely create migration sources that use different database connection keys. I've done it. Whether local or remote. If its behind a firewall or other limitations that is a different story, but Migrate absolutely can connect to database sources. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/migrating-data-from-a-sql-source

Answer (score -2):

in your Settings.php you could include the "external" DB and then run your queries.

for example in settings.php:

```
 $databases['default']['default'] = [
  'database' => // The DB Name,
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'host' => // The DB Host,
  'username' => // DB username,
  'password' => // The DB password,
  'port' => // Mysql port,
];
```

Then in your code, you could switch between both Databases for example:
using

```
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('external');// connect to "source" DB
$db = \Drupal::database();
$db->query(); // Perform your queries here and get the results you need
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();// Connect to "destination" DB
// create your nodes using the data retrieved from the query above.
```

I suggest reading more here:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/static-queries

and: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Database.php/class/Database/10

Comment: The question is about importing external data, not querying it.

Comment: True, but part of importing the data is querying it. as they stated in the question. 

i just put guidance on when to query and when to start creating nodes